# Create graphs on graph paper to scale

Tags: information-graphics, traditional-media

For a science lab, I am required to draw precise graphs on physical graph paper. The process is tedious as the graphs need to be drawn to precise scale and require using small numbers (such as .05). The graphs must use the full paper which has blocks that are 1mm by 1mm.

Is there any way to make this somewhat less tedious? Are there tools that are made to help create the scale or help outline the plots?

Thank you

Comment: CAD or mathematical applications come to mind. What is the purpose of the picture?

Comment: Unfortunately the purpose is for a homework assignment

Comment: In that case, have you considered that being tedious IS the aim.

Comment: @joojaa as was the case with all homework, in my eyes! hahah